# Namespace attributes added to XML output

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm producing an XML output using an XSLT transform.
I added a BizData and Pyld nodes to surround the header and payload data.
I get an unwanted namespace attribute that appears on the BizData and Pyld that I am not sure where that comes from.

I have removed all the data from the Document tag as it is a lot but that is all populated as expected.

XSLT is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />

    <xsl:template match="/Root/node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="vrtfPass1Result">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:apply-templates mode="mPass2"
        select="ext:node-set($vrtfPass1Result)/*"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/Root">
    <BizData>
        <Hdr>
            <AppHdr>
                <CharSet>String</CharSet>
                <Fr>
                    <OrgId>
                        <Id>
                            <OrgId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>4ABC</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </OrgId>
                        </Id>
                    </OrgId>
                </Fr>
                <To>
                    <OrgId>
                        <Id>
                            <OrgId>
                                <Othr>
                                    <Id>DRRL</Id>
                                </Othr>
                            </OrgId>
                        </Id>
                    </OrgId>
                </To>
                <BizMsgIdr>EUSF</BizMsgIdr>
                <MsgDefIdr>a</MsgDefIdr>
                <CreDt>2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</CreDt>
            </AppHdr>
        </Hdr>
    </BizData>
    <Pyld>
    <Document>
        .....       
    </Document>
    </Pyld>
    </xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" mode="mPass2">
        <xsl:if test="normalize-space(.) != '' or ./@* != ''">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="mPass2"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match=
        "*[not(@*|*|comment()|processing-instruction()) 
         and normalize-space()=''
          ]" mode="mPass2"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<BizData xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">   <<<WHY IS THERE THE ATTRIBUTE ADDED HERE
  <Hdr>
    <AppHdr>
      <CharSet>String</CharSet>
      <Fr>
        <OrgId>
          <Id>
            <OrgId>
              <Othr>
                <Id>4ABC</Id>
              </Othr>
            </OrgId>
          </Id>
        </OrgId>
      </Fr>
      <To>
        <OrgId>
          <Id>
            <OrgId>
              <Othr>
                <Id>DRRL</Id>
              </Othr>
            </OrgId>
          </Id>
        </OrgId>
      </To>
      <BizMsgIdr>EUSF</BizMsgIdr>
      <MsgDefIdr>a</MsgDefIdr>
      <CreDt>2001-12-17T09:30:47Z</CreDt>
    </AppHdr>
  </Hdr>
</BizData>
<Pyld xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common">    <<<WHY IS THERE THE ATTRIBUTE ADDED HERE
  <Document>
    .....
  </Document>
</Pyld>
```

Not sure why the attribute - xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common" - is populating on those elements...

Thanks in advance,
Saul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an attribute `exclude-result-prefixes="ext"` to the root element of the XSLT to avoid that.

As you have declared `xmlns:ext="http://exslt.org/common"` in your XSLT code the namespace declaration is in scope for any of your result elements (like the `BizData` element and its descendants) so that is why the XSLT processor outputs it for your result document (https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#literal-result-element). Any namespace you only need for selecting nodes from the input or to select extension functions can be declared in the `exclude-result-prefixes` to avoid it being used during a result tree serialization.